# How to apply javascript to multiple ids?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two drop down menus with the id `validKeys1` and `validKeys2`, I'm trying to populate the drop downs from an array using the javascript code below, but it will only populate `validKeys2`. How do I use the same piece of javascript on multiple IDs?

```
var validKeys1 = document.getElementById("validKeys1");
var validKeys2 = document.getElementById("validKeys2");

for(var i = 0; i < validCoursesKeys.length; i++) {
    var opt = validCoursesKeys[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    validKeys1.appendChild(el);
    validKeys2.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: you have to create `option` for each "validKey", you can't use a single HTML element in two places (appendChild will "move" an element from it's current location to where you are appending it - this is why only validKeys2 ends up with options)

Answer (score 2):

[`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) takes the element that is passed and **moves** it into the parent element. Meaning if it is already inside one element it is removed from there and placed into the other.

You can either make a whole new element or use [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to add to your second select

```
validKeys1.appendChild(el);
validKeys2.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use general `class` instead and **[`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)** to duplicate  the node `el` every time you append it :

```
var validKeys = document.getElementsByClassName("validKeys");

for(var i = 0; i < validCoursesKeys.length; i++) {
    var opt = validCoursesKeys[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;

    for(var j = 0; j < validKeys.length; j++) {
         validKeys[j].appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var validCoursesKeys = ['opt 1','opt 2','opt 3','opt 4']
var validKeys = document.getElementsByClassName("validKeys");

for(var i = 0; i < validCoursesKeys.length; i++) {
  var opt = validCoursesKeys[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;

  for(var j = 0; j < validKeys.length; j++) {
    validKeys[j].appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="validKeys"></select>
<select class="validKeys"></select>
<select class="validKeys"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was originally trying to do it with `class` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ndo1xrmk/ but it's obviously wrong.....how is the HTML supposed to look for this to work?? (Sorry, super new to HTML/JS. Been using for like three days)

Comment: using class isn't the solution - it's the `clone` that solves the problem

Comment: @JaromandaX is right the main idea is about cloning the node `el` so we can append it to multiple list, but IMO using class in this case is more efficient than ids.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki we posted so close together I missed the snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually appending the option element to validKeys1 and then changing its parent to validKeys2. This should work as you expected.

```
var validKeys1 = document.getElementById("validKeys1");
var validKeys2 = document.getElementById("validKeys2");

for(var i = 0; i < validCoursesKeys.length; i++) {
    var opt = validCoursesKeys[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    validKeys1.appendChild(el);
    var el2 = el.cloneNode(false);
    validKeys2.appendChild(el2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this might be also useful, using the forEach method on array

```
var validKeys1 = document.getElementById("validKeys1");
var validKeys2 = document.getElementById("validKeys2");
[validKeys1, validKeys2].forEach((ids) => {
     validCoursesKeys.forEach((courses) => {
        var opt = courses
        var el = document.createElement('option');
        el.textConent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        ids.appendChild(el)
   })
})
```